# Detect phone number during call entry

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to detect on iOS the incoming number during ringing to use it into an action. 
It is possible in iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Apple do not provide an API for this.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible to track  incoming phone calls in iphone sdk. If you do this with some private API your app will get rejected from app store.